# How to inject EntityFramework Core DbContext in Repository

Tags: c#, entity-framework, autofac, entity-framework-core, botframework

Most of the examples online deal with asp.net and register their DbContext as part of their startup service registry.

I tried registering my DbContext like this

```
builder.RegisterType<MyContext>()
    .As<MyContext>()
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

builder.RegisterType<DealRepository>()
    .Keyed<IRepository<Deal>>(FiberModule.Key_DoNotSerialize)
    .As<IRepository<Deal>>()
    .SingleInstance();

builder.RegisterType<CardsDialog>()
    .As<IDialog<object>>()
    .InstancePerDependency();
```

But I'm getting this error

> Inheritance security rules violated by type:
>   'System.Net.Http.WebRequestHandler'. Derived types must either match
>   the security accessibility of the base type or be less accessible.

It's even more complicated as the actual `MessageController.cs` creates a new scope on `Post`

```
using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(Conversation.Container, activity))
{
    var dialog = scope.Resolve<IDialog<object>>();

    await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => dialog);

}
```

How should the registering be done?

EDIT:
As suggested, using `InstancePerRequest` solved the problem. But I also have a Quartz jobs that runs every X seconds that also needs a repository.

```
builder.RegisterType<DealJob>()
    .AsSelf()
    .SingleInstance();
```

> Unable to resolve the type 'BargainBot.Repositories.MyContext' because
>   the lifetime scope it belongs in can't be located. The following
>   services are exposed by this registration:
>   - BargainBot.Repositories.MyContext
>
> Details ---> No scope with a tag matching 'AutofacWebRequest' is
>   visible from the scope in which the instance was requested. If you see this during execution of a web application, it generally indicates that a component registered as per-HTTP request is being requested by a SingleInstance()

Should I resolve a new DbContext manually at this point? Or maybe I should change the my repo's life cycle?

Edit2: Looks like I'm still getting this error even when removing the entire Quartz job registration.

Comment: You try to register your context as builder.RegisterType<MyContext>().InstancePerRequest();

Comment: Why don't you add your DbContext to `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup.cs`?  Something like `services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));` And add your Repository there as well: `services.AddScoped<IDealRepository, DealRepository>();`

Comment: I don't have a `Startup.cs` as I'm not in a asp.net context. This is in a MicrosoftBot Framework application. I'll clarify in the original question.

Comment: You can try to register InstancePerLifetimeScope() instead of InstancePerRequest() for MyContext

Comment: @HaHoang Yes, that's what I had in my initial question.

Comment: Try to register your context as builder.RegisterType<MyContext>().InstancePerLifetimeScope()

Comment: If you want to inject interfaces, rather than implementations into your classes, you should be registered as *builder.RegisterType<MyContext>().As<IMyContext>()*. Also have a look at http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/registration.html#services-vs-components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was wrong about the issue, it wasn't an IoC and DbContext issue. Seems like it was in the .NET platform itself

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/9846#issuecomment-274707732

Adding a redirect did the trick

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Answer (score 4):

I was having a similar issue and after a lot of back and forth the following code worked for me:

**DbContext**

```
 public class SalesDbContext : DbContext
{
    public SalesDbContext(DbContextOptions<SalesDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Domain.Product.Product> Products { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        // Configure database attributes
    }



}
```

**Repository**

```
 public class ProductRepository : IProductRepository
{
    private readonly SalesDbContext _db;

    public ProductRepository(SalesDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }


}
```

**Autofac Module**

```
 public class DefaultModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        // Register Entity Framework
        var dbContextOptionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<SalesDbContext>().UseSqlServer("MyConnectionString");

        builder.RegisterType<SalesDbContext>()
            .WithParameter("options", dbContextOptionsBuilder.Options)
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope(); 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

installing System.Net.Http 4.3.1 solved my problem